# Geoserver Rest API add coverage from existing coveragestore - java.lang.RuntimeException

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-rest-api

i got an **error when trying to create a new coverage from an existing coveragestore in geoserver with REST api**.
I first created a new store manually in the web administration interface as i am more firm with this. Then I just copied the contents from the newly craeted store as .json (for example from "https://myserver/geoserver/rest/workspaces/myworkspace/coveragestores/myNewStore.json") and saved it as "newCoverageStore.json". I deleted the store and add it again with curl. My goal is to later do this with a lot of files via python, so i can't rely on manually creating the stores and coverages in the web interface.

```
curl -u admin:geoserver -v -XPOST -H 'Content-type:application/json' 
-d @newCoverageStore.json  
https://myserver/geoserver/rest/workspaces/myworkspace/coveragestores.json
```

**This worked totally fine**, created a new store called "myNewStore" and i now did the same with the coverage layer i want to publish from the store. So i published a coverage layer in the web interface. Copied the contents to as .json and again tried to add it with curl to geoserver.

```
curl -u admin:geoserver -v -XPOST -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d @newCoverage.json  
https://myserver/geoserver/rest/workspaces/myworkspace/coveragestores/myNewStore/coverages.json
```

with following .json:

```
{
   "coverage":{
      "name":"myNewLayer",
      "nativeName":"myNewLayer",
      "namespace":{
         "name":"myworkspace",
         "href":"https:\/\/myserver\/geoserver\/rest\/namespaces\/myworkspace.json"
      },
      "title":"myNewLayer",
      "description":"Generated from ImageMosaic",
      "keywords":{
         "string":[
            "myNewLayer",
            "WCS",
            "ImageMosaic"
         ]
      },
      "nativeCRS":"GEOGCS[\"WGS 84\", \n  DATUM[\"World Geodetic System 1984\", \n    SPHEROID[\"WGS 84\", 6378137.0, 298.257223563, AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"7030\"]], \n    AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"6326\"]], \n  PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\", 0.0, AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"8901\"]], \n  UNIT[\"degree\", 0.017453292519943295], \n  AXIS[\"Geodetic longitude\", EAST], \n  AXIS[\"Geodetic latitude\", NORTH], \n  AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"4326\"]]",
      "srs":"EPSG:4326",
      "nativeBoundingBox":{
         "minx":-26.86,
         "maxx":21.1,
         "miny":-1.7399999999999984,
         "maxy":28.400000000000002,
         "crs":"EPSG:4326"
      },
      "latLonBoundingBox":{
         "minx":-26.86,
         "maxx":21.1,
         "miny":-1.7399999999999984,
         "maxy":28.400000000000002,
         "crs":"EPSG:4326"
      },
      "projectionPolicy":"REPROJECT_TO_DECLARED",
      "enabled":true,
      "metadata":{
         "entry":[
            {
               "@key":"elevation",
               "dimensionInfo":{
                  "enabled":false
               }
            },
            {
               "@key":"time",
               "dimensionInfo":{
                  "enabled":true,
                  "presentation":"LIST",
                  "units":"ISO8601",
                  "defaultValue":"",
                  "nearestMatchEnabled":false,
                  "rawNearestMatchEnabled":false
               }
            },
            {
               "@key":"cachingEnabled",
               "$":"false"
            },
            {
               "@key":"dirName",
               "$":"cddrs_projection_diff_rcm_rcp85_rcp85"
            }
         ]
      },
      "store":{
         "@class":"coverageStore",
         "name":"myworkspace:mynewStore",
         "href":"https:\/\/myserver\/geoserver\/rest\/workspaces\/myworkspace\/coveragestores\/myNewStore.json"
      },
      "serviceConfiguration":false,
      "simpleConversionEnabled":false,
      "internationalTitle":"",
      "internationalAbstract":"",
      "nativeFormat":"ImageMosaic",
      "grid":{
         "@dimension":"2",
         "range":{
            "low":"0 0",
            "high":"218 137"
         },
         "transform":{
            "scaleX":0.22,
            "scaleY":-0.22,
            "shearX":0,
            "shearY":0,
            "translateX":-26.75,
            "translateY":28.290000000000003
         },
         "crs":"EPSG:4326"
      },
      "supportedFormats":{
         "string":[
            "GEOTIFF",
            "GIF",
            "PNG",
            "JPEG",
            "TIFF"
         ]
      },
      "interpolationMethods":{
         "string":[
            "nearest neighbor",
            "bilinear",
            "bicubic"
         ]
      },
      "defaultInterpolationMethod":"nearest neighbor",
      "dimensions":{
         "coverageDimension":[
            {
               "name":"GRAY_INDEX",
               "description":"GridSampleDimension[-Infinity,Infinity]",
               "range":{
                  "min":"-inf",
                  "max":"inf"
               },
               "dimensionType":{
                  "name":"REAL_32BITS"
               }
            }
         ]
      },
      "requestSRS":{
         "string":[
            "EPSG:4326"
         ]
      },
      "responseSRS":{
         "string":[
            "EPSG:4326"
         ]
      },
      "parameters":{
         "entry":[
            {
               "string":"BackgroundValues",
               "null":""
            },
            {
               "string":[
                  "OVERVIEW_POLICY",
                  "QUALITY"
               ]
            },
            {
               "string":[
                  "MergeBehavior",
                  "FLAT"
               ]
            },
            {
               "string":"AllowMultithreading",
               "boolean":false
            },
            {
               "string":"MaxAllowedTiles",
               "int":-1
            },
            {
               "string":[
                  "ExcessGranuleRemoval",
                  "NONE"
               ]
            },
            {
               "string":"OutputTransparentColor",
               "null":""
            },
            {
               "string":"USE_JAI_IMAGEREAD",
               "boolean":true
            },
            {
               "string":"Bands",
               "null":""
            },
            {
               "string":"RescalePixels",
               "boolean":true
            },
            {
               "string":"Filter",
               "null":""
            },
            {
               "string":"InputTransparentColor",
               "null":""
            },
            {
               "string":[
                  "SUGGESTED_TILE_SIZE",
                  "512,512"
               ]
            },
            {
               "string":"Accurate resolution computation",
               "boolean":false
            },
            {
               "string":"SORTING",
               "null":""
            },
            {
               "string":[
                  "FootprintBehavior",
                  "None"
               ]
            },
            "rcp85"
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

**This did not work as expected** from my first similar test with the coverageStore and curl gives me an HTTP/2 500.
The **error log** unfortunately did not give me any helpful hints:

```
2023-10-18 09:56:35,433 ERROR [geoserver.rest] - 
---- Debugging information ----
cause-exception     : java.lang.RuntimeException
cause-message       : null
class               : java.util.HashMap
required-type       : java.util.HashMap
converter-type      : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.MapConverter
line number         : -1
class[1]            : org.geoserver.catalog.impl.CoverageInfoImpl
required-type[1]    : org.geoserver.catalog.impl.CoverageInfoImpl
converter-type[1]   : org.geoserver.config.util.XStreamPersister$CoverageInfoConverter
version             : 2.20.4
-------------------------------
com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: 
---- Debugging information ----
cause-exception     : java.lang.RuntimeException
cause-message       : null
class               : java.util.HashMap
required-type       : java.util.HashMap
converter-type      : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.MapConverter
line number         : -1
class[1]            : org.geoserver.catalog.impl.CoverageInfoImpl
required-type[1]    : org.geoserver.catalog.impl.CoverageInfoImpl
converter-type[1]   : org.geoserver.config.util.XStreamPersister$CoverageInfoConverter
version             : 2.20.4
-------------------------------
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:77)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:499)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:425)
    at org.geoserver.config.util.XStreamPersister$ResourceInfoConverter.doUnmarshal(XStreamPersister.java:2012)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:277)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.start(TreeUnmarshaller.java:134)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.unmarshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:32)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1487)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1467)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:1347)
    at org.geoserver.config.util.XStreamPersister.load(XStreamPersister.java:718)
    at org.geoserver.rest.converters.XStreamJSONMessageConverter.readInternal(XStreamJSONMessageConverter.java:60)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:199)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.readWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.readWithMessageConverters(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:158)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:131)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:167)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:134)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:878)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:792)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1043)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.handleNonCORS(CorsFilter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:176)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:28)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.ows.HTTPHeadersCollector.doFilter(HTTPHeadersCollector.java:48)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:70)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:43)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:39)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:52)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:142)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.geoserver.filters.XFrameOptionsFilter.doFilter(XFrameOptionsFilter.java:77)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:54)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:49)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:42)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:660)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)
    at org.apache.coyote.http2.StreamProcessor.service(StreamProcessor.java:426)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.http2.StreamProcessor.process(StreamProcessor.java:87)
    at org.apache.coyote.http2.StreamRunnable.run(StreamRunnable.java:35)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.AbstractPullReader.moveDown(AbstractPullReader.java:105)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.AbstractCollectionConverter.readCompleteItem(AbstractCollectionConverter.java:146)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.MapConverter.putCurrentEntryIntoMap(MapConverter.java:105)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.MapConverter.populateMap(MapConverter.java:98)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.MapConverter.populateMap(MapConverter.java:92)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.MapConverter.unmarshal(MapConverter.java:87)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
    ... 123 more
```

It would be great if someone can give me some hints what went wrong here, if the curl call is incorrect or if there is something wrong with the .json file i posted to geoserver, although i just copied it and tried to reproduce the workflow in the web administration interface.

Comment: Something is wrong with your JSON and GeoServer can't read it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Ian Turton was right, something was wrong with the Json.
**I excluded the "parameters"** section at the bottom of the json and the creation via curl worked fine.
I guess i have do look further what caused the problem, but right know that seemed to be the main issue.